# Google Maps API Doesn't Return LatLng from Extended Zip Code - USA - 9 digit Zip code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following shows Lat and Long

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90005

But with extended Zip code, it doesn't

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=900053200

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Is there a separate service for extended Zip codes?

Comment: posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The format required for zip + 4 is 90005-3200.

Using that format gives me a result (the same result as for zip code 90005).

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90005-3200&key=MY-API-KEY
```

returns:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "90005",
               "short_name" : "90005",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Central LA",
               "short_name" : "Central LA",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Los Angeles, CA 90005, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0637149,
                  "lng" : -118.282294
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.05513,
                  "lng" : -118.3393861
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.0578814,
               "lng" : -118.3096648
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.0637149,
                  "lng" : -118.282294
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.05513,
                  "lng" : -118.3393861
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJ0U_geYS4woAR6-RMnUWG2Gc",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```